# Error message by trying to compile code using "x86_amd64\cl.exe" to generate 64bit application

Tags: 64-bit, windows-xp, cross-compiling, 32-bit, cl

I got this error message by trying to compile small piece of code using "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\bin\x86_amd64\cl.exe" to generate 64bit application

"The application or DLL c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\BIN\amd64\mspdb80.dll is not a valid Windows image. Please check this aganist your installation diskette"

Comment: Well, that's accurate, a 32-bit process cannot use a 64-bit DLL.  Hard to guess how this happened, your question is very inadequately documented.  Probably used the wrong Visual Studio Command Prompt, you need the 32-bit flavor.  Use the IDE instead.

Comment: Hi @HansPassant , Thanks for your reply,
As far as i know all what i have to do in order to compile 64bit app. on 32bit OS is that i have to use cl in this directory c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\BIN\amd64\mspdb80.dll
Am i missing something?